# MySQL Case function behave strange and inconstent

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

We are using MySQL 8 as our java application DB.

We have a query with the following format:

```
select 
id,
group_concat(NAME ORDER BY ID separator ',,') AS Code,
CASE
WHEN MAX(p.VARIABLEfactor) = 1 THEN MAX(i.factor) ELSE MAX(p.factor) END AS factor

from MA_TABLE
join TABLE_P p on (...)
join TABLE_I i on (...)

 group by id
```

The query worked very fine in our development environments until deploy with client where the factor column is getting null.

We have run the same query in the client environment from MySQL Workbench and we can see that the factor column is getting well populated.

After some debugging,we changed :

```
CASE
WHEN MAX(p.VARIABLEfactor) = 1 THEN MAX(i.factor) ELSE MAX(p.factor) END AS factor
```

to

```
MAX(
WHEN p.VARIABLEfactor = 1 THEN i.factor ELSE p.factor END ) AS factor,
```

and the query worked correctly.

Any help here please?

Comment: They do different things, the results Should be different, they are not in any way comparable. Please describe what you're Trying to do and we'll help you determine which (if either) is correct.

Comment: Help with what? What's the goal here?

Comment: This is really a case of understanding the *data* - we can't do that.

Comment: My first question is what make the same query to return expected data when run in workbench but return records with empty factor column when run within my java application.Is there any session configuration different in both clients which explain this?

Comment: @Zizou: No, with the same data, you can of course expect the same data, no matter whether you run the query from the workbench or from some java app. But you changed the case expression making it behave completely different and say "the query worked correctly". This indicates that you don't understand the difference of the two expressions, but it is vital. So, maybe you are just confused by the result you see, because you mistakenly expected it must be different.

Comment: `My first question is what make the same query to return expected data when run in workbench but return records with empty factor column when run within my java application` : That's simple. Either the ***data*** is different in each scenario, or the ***code*** is different in each scenario. Perhaps one is running against a test database, or a different client's data. Perhaps the java is discarding or otherwise corrupting the returned value.  But the following remain true: That SQL ***can't*** return different results for the same data, your revised CASE does ***not*** do the same calculation.

Comment: Please run this and add the results to your question *(limited to a single `id` that you know is problematic)*  `SELECT MA_TABLE.id, MA_TABLE.VARIABLEfactor, CASE WHEN i.factor IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS i_factor_null, CASE WHEN p.factor IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS p_factor_null, COUNT(*) AS row_count FROM MA_TABLE join TABLE_P p on (...) join TABLE_I i on (...) WHERE MA_TABLE.id = ????? GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4`  Ideally from both the java application and MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Sorry I can’t paste the complete query but still I am not understanding what is happening.I will review it again carefully and update you

Comment: I'm ***guessing*** you mean that the debug-query gave too many rows?  This may give fewer rows *(you still need to run it for just one problem id)*: `SELECT MA_TABLE.id, CASE WHEN MA_TABLE.VARIABLEfactor < 1 THEN '<1' WHEN MA_TABLE.VARIABLEfactor = 1 THEN '=1' WHEN MA_TABLE.VARIABLEfactor > 1 THEN '>1' END AS VARIABLE, CASE WHEN i.factor IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS i_factor_null, CASE WHEN p.factor IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS p_factor_null, COUNT(*) AS row_count FROM MA_TABLE join TABLE_P p on (...) join TABLE_I i on (...) WHERE MA_TABLE.id = ??? GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4`

Answer (score 2):

From your explanation I gather that you don't understand the difference of your two case expressions. But they are very different. Let's look at an example for one ID:

| ID | VARIABLEfactor | i.factor | p.factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0 | null | 10 |
| 100 | 1 | null | 20 |

Your expression

```
CASE WHEN MAX(p.VARIABLEfactor) = 1 THEN MAX(i.factor) ELSE MAX(p.factor) END
```

looks at the maximum `VARIABLEfactor`, which is 1, so the `THEN` case applies and the maximum `i.factor` is returned. This is null, as all `i.factor` are null.

Your expression

```
MAX(WHEN p.VARIABLEfactor = 1 THEN i.factor ELSE p.factor END)
```

looks at each row's `VARIABLEfactor`. For the first row this is 0, so the `ELSE` case applies and `p.factor` 10 is used. For the second row the `VARIABLEfactor` is 1, so its `i.factor` null gets used. Of these you take the maximum, which is 10.

To recap: The first expression is just a `CASE` expression on the aggregation results. It returns null here. The second expression is a conditional aggregation. It returns 10 for the sample data.

Comment: There's also the possibility the `MAX(VARIALBEfactor)` is greater than 1.  But, yes, the principle problem is that the OP doesn't understand what the code is doing...  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90be74795a0e8bed7cffd340ad9cd88d

Comment: For the same id, i will always have the same record from TABLE_P and TABLE_I (than the same factor and variable factor)

Comment: The same query was executed correctly in workbench but return null value for factor column in my application

Comment: The only logic explanation which explain the result I'm getting is that my:
CASE WHEN MAX(p.VARIABLEfactor) = 1 THEN MAX(i.factor) ELSE MAX(p.factor) END
Is not taking into account the group by clause

Comment: @zizou No, No, No. Stop using magical thinking. If that expression is giving NULL, then one of the columns (in that group) is full of NULLs.  Go to the link in the first comment on this answer, play with it and try to replicate your assertion. If you can't replicate it, you CAN'T make the assertion. Then run the code I asked in the comments on the question. That will diagnose where and when you have NULLs.  Start listening to people who have DECADES of experience in SQL, debugging and diagnostics.